# OpenWeatherMap API - Dates in XML

Tags: php, xml, openweathermap

Anyone can explain to me in which format are these DateTime strings from OpenWeatherMap API and how to work with them in order to:

Just see the time (Greenwich +1)

```
sun rise="2019-01-28T06:31:03" set="2019-01-28T16:14:39"
```

View the Date & Time (Greenwich +1)

```
lastupdate value="2019-01-28T11:20:00"
```

Comment: If you show us the actual XML you have questions about, it will be much easier for us to understand. Please edit your question to include a proper example.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for replying. Here it is. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: That looks like normal time strings. Have you tried converting them to `DateTime`-objects? Then you can do pretty much what you want with them. Please show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Those dates are in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

The examples you actually have do NOT contain any TimeZone information so they could be any timezone..

If you work with datetime offsets (that include time zone information) you would typically see something like this

> 2008-09-15T15:53:00+05:00

The reasone it is formatted in ISO 8601 is so that the date time picker (that is the actual format you use for the value) on your HTML page knows how to interpret the time into your local (machine clock configured time)

Typically if using UTC you will have a date time that looks like

> 2008-09-15T15:53:00Z

Which is [Zulu Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)

And as i mentioned already if it does not have any of those it is assumed local time at server that generated it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was able to convert them by using concatenated date and strtotime functions.

```
date('H.i',strtotime($sunset_time));
```

The local time on the server is Greenwich, whereas I would need to add +1 for my time zone (Europe/Rome).

In the end I was able to add +1 hour like this:

```
date('H.i', strtotime($sunset_time) + 60*60);
```

Is this a correct way?